# タグ指名の仕組み

Tags: c++, c++11

こんにちは、C++の初学者です。
ビャーネ・ストラウストラップ先生の『プログラミング言語C++　第4版』から以下のexampleを引用しました。
タグ指名(tag dispatch)について、関数sort_helperの引数に、「random_access_iterator_tag」や「forward_iterator_tag」などと書くことが許されるのは何故でしょうか。なにか特別な文法なのでしょうか。ご教授願います。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template<typename C>
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;

template<typename C>
using Iterator_type = typename C::iterator;

template<typename Iter>
using Iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category;

template<typename Ran>
void sort_helper(Ran beg, Ran end, random_access_iterator_tag) {
    sort(beg,end);
}

template<typename For>
void sort_helper(For beg, For end, forward_iterator_tag) {
    vector<Value_type<For>> v {beg, end};
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),beg);
}

template<typename C>
void sort(C& c) {
    using Iter = Iterator_type<C>;
    sort_helper(c.begin(),c.end(),Iterator_category<Iter>{});
}

template<typename C>
void print(C& c) {
    for (auto p : c) {
        cout << p << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec {1,2,4,5,7,8,5,6,98,78,45,12,65};
    list<int> lst {1,2,5,8,9,6,3,4,7,32,65,45,12,13};
    // sort
    sort(vec);
    sort(lst);
    // print
    print(vec);
    print(lst);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) では関数内部で使わない仮引数は引数名を省略できます ([c](/questions/tagged/c) は禁止)

```
void func(int f, int g, int) { ... }
void func(int f, int g, double) { ... }
```

と全く同じことで、提示 `sort_helper()` は引数３つをとる関数で、その３つ目の引数はコンパイル時オーバーロード解決にのみ使い、実行時には使っていないのです。

```
func(x, y, int()); // は先の例の前者を呼ぶ
func(x, y, traits<T>::value{}); // value 型に適合するほうが呼ばれる
```

使われない引数１つを受け渡す実行時オーバーヘッドがかかりますが、それ以上に得られるものがあるとき使われます。

Comment: 質問者さんの知りたいことの中心は「オーバーロード」の仕組みの中身のような気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。関数内部で使わない仮引数について、引数名を省略できることを知りませんでした。まさにこのことをを知りたかったのでした。解決しました。

Comment: なるほど、済みません、蛇足コメントでしたね。